# How to set default value of bunch of KendoUI DropDownLists when binding to IEnumerable and using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, dropdownlistfor

I am having this model (containing `IEnumerable` of `int`s) and I want to create KendoUI `DropDownList` for each of the elements in this `IEnumerable`:

```
public class PlayersInGameViewModel
{
    public PlayersInGameViewModel()
    {
        this.FirstTeamPlayers = Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Select(x => 0).ToList();
    }

    public IList<int> FirstTeamPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have an action to provide the data for drop downs (it isn't important but I am sharing it for the sake of completeness):

```
public ActionResult PlayersRead()
{
    var result =
        this.players.All()
            .Select(x => new { Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName, Value = x.Id })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
    result.Insert(0, new { Name = "-----------", Value = 0 });
    return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this is the part of my view where I am creating the `DropDownList`s:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.FirstTeamPlayers[i])
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .Filter("contains")
        .MinLength(1)
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("PlayersRead", "PlayersInGames");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(false);
        }) 
    )
    <br />
}
```

The problem is that when I set a for one of the elements in `FirstTeamPlayers` I want them to be populated when loading the DropDown widget:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var viewModel = this.Mapper.Map<PlayersInGameViewModel>(this.games.GetById(id));
    viewModel.FirstTeamPlayers[2] = 3;
    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

Here is the result as HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="FirstTeamPlayers_2_" name="FirstTeamPlayers[2]" type="text" value="3" />
<script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#FirstTeamPlayers_2_").kendoDropDownList({"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Administration/PlayersInGames/PlayersRead"},"prefix":""},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"dataTextField":"Name","filter":"contains","minLength":1,"valuePrimitive":true,"dataValueField":"Value"});});
</script>
```

As you can see everything seems to be correctly generated and `value="3"` is present in the HTML but the widget in the browser is showing the default value for all dropdowns:

[image: 8 KendoUI DropDowns]

There are no JavaScript errors on the console.

What am I missing? **Why does KendoUI doesn't respect the given value?**

**EDIT:**

Also all the values are loaded correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using a workaround: setting the value through the `.SelectedIndex(Model.FirstTeamPlayers[i])` method in the `Kendo().DropDownListFor()` helper.

Here is my working view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.FirstTeamPlayers[i])
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .Filter("contains")
        .SelectedIndex(Model.FirstTeamPlayers[i])
        .MinLength(1)
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("PlayersRead", "PlayersInGames");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(false);
        }) 
    )
}
```